# Surprising type inference for named field in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Consider the following transcript of GHCi, version 8.2.2:

```hs
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XRankNTypes
Prelude> data Functor f = Functor { fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b }
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f1 -> (a -> b) -> f2 a -> f2 b
Prelude> :t Functor map
Functor map :: Functor []
Prelude> :t fmap (Functor map)
fmap (Functor map) :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

As you can see, the type of `fmap` is inferred as `Functor f1 -> (a -> b) -> f2 a -> f2 b`. This is surprising because `f1` and `f2` are supposed to be the same type variable but there's no `f1 ~ f2` constraint. Nevertheless, if you apply `fmap` to `Functor map` which has the type `Functor []`, the result still has the type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` as expected. What's going on here? I would have expected `fmap` to have the type `Functor f -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Comment: Smells like a bug to me.

Comment: My GHCi version 8.0.2 returns `fmap :: Functor f -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` for `:t fmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this issue affects GHC 8.2.2 but not 8.0.2.
**Update:**  It looks like it's been fixed on the 8.4 branch.

It appears to be a GHCi type signature display bug, rather than a real type checker issue, since if you take the program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Inference where
data Functor f = Functor { fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b }
```

and compile it with `ghc -ddump-tc`, you can see that GHC infers the correct type:

```
TYPE SIGNATURES
  ...
  Inference.fmap ::
    forall (f :: * -> *).
    Inference.Functor f -> forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It also doesn't seem to affect GHC error messages.  If you add the line:

```
main = print Inference.fmap
```

to produce an error message that includes the type ("No instance for (Show xxx)"), you *also* see the correct type.